# Core Data 'File "Contents" couldn't be opened'

Tags: xcode, core-data, core-data-migration

I made the silly mistake and I accidentially touch my current Core Data model instead the new version one I just created. So I went to source control and reverted the changes inside the `**.xcdatamodeld` group. However I have now a zombie entry in the project structure inside this group (its the new version `**.xcdatamodel` I have created) that I can't open (message like in the title). Probably because reverting deleting the files but somehow the reference is still there.

Just a little bit annoying. Tried cleaning, closing & reopening.

Comment: The .xcdatamodel is a directory. Maybe you have some bad reference witihn it.

Comment: Further details? hmm... well i think thats all there is. Yes it is a directory but it physically doesn't exist anymore. Still there is a reference to it in xcode somehow i can't get rid of.

Answer (score 1):

I had two files with the same name, but only one showed in Xcode. This fixed it:

1. Locate the **.xcdatamodeld file in your project
2. Right click and select 'Show Package Contents'
3. Locate the two files with the same name
4. Delete the one that is Zero bytes in size
5. Rebuild and smile