# How can I restore a CoreData Model version that has gone missing?

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

So, I've screwed up. I created a new version of an existing CoreData model in Xcode and somehow never ended up committing the `.xcdatamodel` file (or more accurately, the `contents` file within). Now, a while later, that file has gone missing and I have no way of restoring it. Trying to open the xcdatamodel file in xcode gives me the error "The file "contents" couldn't be opened because there is no such file".

I thought I could be smart and copy the `contents` file from a previous version `.xcdatamodel` file, and then just add back the table I'd added for this migration (fortunately I'd only added the one table and generated a class, so creating the table again was easy). Problem is, when I run the app on the simulator or a device where data is already present, I get the following error: `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134130.)"`

The error also lists the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator's current model hashes, so now I assume it's probable that the hash for the model in question is different.

What are my options here? How can I fix the data so that users won't have to uninstall the app and lose all their data before updating?

Below is the complete contents of the error:

```
2015-01-21 11:01:11.050 Marq[2699:607] CoreData: annotation: Incompatible version schema for persistent store 'file:///Users/aerion/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/71815540-57DE-49BF-A6F6-69500A54281F/data/Applications/EE5B15A6-A5ED-46EB-9DFD-B6B54353E35B/Documents/ARUPInspect_Schema.sqlite'.  store metadata = {
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 479;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
        Asset = <4b2b421f 4295c02f 89b5a2e8 1c4fc3e9 2b515eca 95e89ad6 e65c891d f82b1090>;
        BooleanValue = <3e1758f6 0f04f670 5c150cd4 55f0a0eb b5c1a17e 8b1abdcc ab7044ba fd02dd5e>;
        Client = <c52499f9 a0f482f7 9bdcb115 8217e157 1861f63a e926b55c e7cc85bb b4044464>;
        DataValue = <43afe89a 90c53a31 4b839b5f b914896b 8ad165de dd46a159 6aac5f86 2d75058c>;
        DataValueCollection = <78dce1b0 9f20a1a9 15004f99 65d71d00 46e7c949 80d599ea 622b2574 be9245a4>;
        DateValue = <54571596 1267b4f2 5f14ee12 a0be1b3f 53d79056 7d612f33 e827b90e 7c4c847b>;
        DirectoryItem = <b716a315 e40d91b6 18bb918e ab448086 48bc62b2 5a26e959 2c4a0cb4 8fc8d319>;
        DirectoryNode = <c718b896 a2a90890 596409a2 c50240aa 1e5e347c f9d9c4df 1a5567fe 8bca7ed3>;
        DoubleValue = <b63cba59 de2b200e 199c5ec4 ce17494a a8df75be bac353c0 3c5d9af7 fbf36240>;
        Group = <0e912576 760d5fd4 df8a5bbe 13b7922d 6760a046 ea6fee68 3fcd4bd4 c9de7b3b>;
        Inspection = <e7fc6688 bee2906d 8f8b7f5e 4f69d1da 59bdbb17 0a620529 c0abc426 d164a44f>;
        InspectionMetaData = <982fe134 141245a4 97ca1cde aaa04843 90746c85 80ddedcc ed63b9a4 b3d40477>;
        IntegerValue = <97fbd40d a463d4ed 282aa03b 4b5892fe 7fcac137 b4cc590b 03d79bb9 cfee4517>;
        Observation = <651371ad be372494 10e31b83 509db973 6021af3b 79895e59 f38e0a9f 0b35a63e>;
        ObservationGroup = <92f680bb b4b5243c 83b665e6 35e0d569 634aa24f 455de69e c8c3b666 84c6a858>;
        Project = <97879f96 cdc99c88 6e6a614f aa81519b 2ba1f415 e4424a57 66d3f32e 3700829f>;
        ProjectPreferredTemplate = <35381035 33dac226 aaeee194 fcd8ad4c e5c5506f a2c597ce 24ba7256 6f34f084>;
        SchemaDataRepresentation = <c1843de9 2192b6f8 8f68d807 d5b0d2ac ab276b3c 67c48dc4 f363d92d 89ce1019>;
        StringValue = <a7948007 c3454244 7cea0dcd c85b69b5 db5501fb 35e2a242 31907b97 558f1fb0>;
        TemplateMetaData = <8f0702e9 8bbb5d4f 71c6a455 2a344af6 e967b2bb abcf05d3 96cd9ffc 328fe362>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "4512A0DB-E887-4294-9E75-840B9861ECA8";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
} and current model versions = {
    Asset = <4b2b421f 4295c02f 89b5a2e8 1c4fc3e9 2b515eca 95e89ad6 e65c891d f82b1090>;
    BooleanValue = <3e1758f6 0f04f670 5c150cd4 55f0a0eb b5c1a17e 8b1abdcc ab7044ba fd02dd5e>;
    Client = <c52499f9 a0f482f7 9bdcb115 8217e157 1861f63a e926b55c e7cc85bb b4044464>;
    DataValue = <43afe89a 90c53a31 4b839b5f b914896b 8ad165de dd46a159 6aac5f86 2d75058c>;
    DataValueCollection = <cb0da8d0 a2c307de 53600c9c 214dfeab bcefc9f0 0507f6e6 1b8ef683 ef608349>;
    DateValue = <54571596 1267b4f2 5f14ee12 a0be1b3f 53d79056 7d612f33 e827b90e 7c4c847b>;
    DirectoryItem = <b716a315 e40d91b6 18bb918e ab448086 48bc62b2 5a26e959 2c4a0cb4 8fc8d319>;
    DirectoryNode = <b9da47a0 bdaf3956 5e75039f e3429a42 bf34d642 871c2f6d 7da7edfa f5380634>;
    DoubleValue = <b63cba59 de2b200e 199c5ec4 ce17494a a8df75be bac353c0 3c5d9af7 fbf36240>;
    Group = <0e912576 760d5fd4 df8a5bbe 13b7922d 6760a046 ea6fee68 3fcd4bd4 c9de7b3b>;
    Inspection = <e7fc6688 bee2906d 8f8b7f5e 4f69d1da 59bdbb17 0a620529 c0abc426 d164a44f>;
    InspectionMetaData = <982fe134 141245a4 97ca1cde aaa04843 90746c85 80ddedcc ed63b9a4 b3d40477>;
    IntegerValue = <97fbd40d a463d4ed 282aa03b 4b5892fe 7fcac137 b4cc590b 03d79bb9 cfee4517>;
    Observation = <651371ad be372494 10e31b83 509db973 6021af3b 79895e59 f38e0a9f 0b35a63e>;
    ObservationGroup = <92f680bb b4b5243c 83b665e6 35e0d569 634aa24f 455de69e c8c3b666 84c6a858>;
    Project = <97879f96 cdc99c88 6e6a614f aa81519b 2ba1f415 e4424a57 66d3f32e 3700829f>;
    ProjectPreferredTemplate = <35381035 33dac226 aaeee194 fcd8ad4c e5c5506f a2c597ce 24ba7256 6f34f084>;
    SchemaDataRepresentation = <c1843de9 2192b6f8 8f68d807 d5b0d2ac ab276b3c 67c48dc4 f363d92d 89ce1019>;
    StringValue = <a7948007 c3454244 7cea0dcd c85b69b5 db5501fb 35e2a242 31907b97 558f1fb0>;
    TemplateMetaData = <8f0702e9 8bbb5d4f 71c6a455 2a344af6 e967b2bb abcf05d3 96cd9ffc 328fe362>;
}
2015-01-21 11:01:11.055 Marq[2699:607] CoreData: annotation: (migration)     will attempt automatic schema migration
2015-01-21 11:01:11.335 Marq[2699:607] CoreData: error: (migration) migration failed with error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134130.)" UserInfo=0x6b58f220 {URL=file:///Users/aerion/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/71815540-57DE-49BF-A6F6-69500A54281F/data/Applications/EE5B15A6-A5ED-46EB-9DFD-B6B54353E35B/Documents/ARUPInspect_Schema.sqlite, metadata={
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 479;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
        Asset = <4b2b421f 4295c02f 89b5a2e8 1c4fc3e9 2b515eca 95e89ad6 e65c891d f82b1090>;
        BooleanValue = <3e1758f6 0f04f670 5c150cd4 55f0a0eb b5c1a17e 8b1abdcc ab7044ba fd02dd5e>;
        Client = <c52499f9 a0f482f7 9bdcb115 8217e157 1861f63a e926b55c e7cc85bb b4044464>;
        DataValue = <43afe89a 90c53a31 4b839b5f b914896b 8ad165de dd46a159 6aac5f86 2d75058c>;
        DataValueCollection = <78dce1b0 9f20a1a9 15004f99 65d71d00 46e7c949 80d599ea 622b2574 be9245a4>;
        DateValue = <54571596 1267b4f2 5f14ee12 a0be1b3f 53d79056 7d612f33 e827b90e 7c4c847b>;
        DirectoryItem = <b716a315 e40d91b6 18bb918e ab448086 48bc62b2 5a26e959 2c4a0cb4 8fc8d319>;
        DirectoryNode = <c718b896 a2a90890 596409a2 c50240aa 1e5e347c f9d9c4df 1a5567fe 8bca7ed3>;
        DoubleValue = <b63cba59 de2b200e 199c5ec4 ce17494a a8df75be bac353c0 3c5d9af7 fbf36240>;
        Group = <0e912576 760d5fd4 df8a5bbe 13b7922d 6760a046 ea6fee68 3fcd4bd4 c9de7b3b>;
        Inspection = <e7fc6688 bee2906d 8f8b7f5e 4f69d1da 59bdbb17 0a620529 c0abc426 d164a44f>;
        InspectionMetaData = <982fe134 141245a4 97ca1cde aaa04843 90746c85 80ddedcc ed63b9a4 b3d40477>;
        IntegerValue = <97fbd40d a463d4ed 282aa03b 4b5892fe 7fcac137 b4cc590b 03d79bb9 cfee4517>;
        Observation = <651371ad be372494 10e31b83 509db973 6021af3b 79895e59 f38e0a9f 0b35a63e>;
        ObservationGroup = <92f680bb b4b5243c 83b665e6 35e0d569 634aa24f 455de69e c8c3b666 84c6a858>;
        Project = <97879f96 cdc99c88 6e6a614f aa81519b 2ba1f415 e4424a57 66d3f32e 3700829f>;
        ProjectPreferredTemplate = <35381035 33dac226 aaeee194 fcd8ad4c e5c5506f a2c597ce 24ba7256 6f34f084>;
        SchemaDataRepresentation = <c1843de9 2192b6f8 8f68d807 d5b0d2ac ab276b3c 67c48dc4 f363d92d 89ce1019>;
        StringValue = <a7948007 c3454244 7cea0dcd c85b69b5 db5501fb 35e2a242 31907b97 558f1fb0>;
        TemplateMetaData = <8f0702e9 8bbb5d4f 71c6a455 2a344af6 e967b2bb abcf05d3 96cd9ffc 328fe362>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "4512A0DB-E887-4294-9E75-840B9861ECA8";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
}, reason=Can't find model for source store}
Error User Info: {
    URL = "file:///Users/aerion/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/71815540-57DE-49BF-A6F6-69500A54281F/data/Applications/EE5B15A6-A5ED-46EB-9DFD-B6B54353E35B/Documents/ARUPInspect_Schema.sqlite";
    metadata =     {
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 479;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
            Asset = <4b2b421f 4295c02f 89b5a2e8 1c4fc3e9 2b515eca 95e89ad6 e65c891d f82b1090>;
            BooleanValue = <3e1758f6 0f04f670 5c150cd4 55f0a0eb b5c1a17e 8b1abdcc ab7044ba fd02dd5e>;
            Client = <c52499f9 a0f482f7 9bdcb115 8217e157 1861f63a e926b55c e7cc85bb b4044464>;
            DataValue = <43afe89a 90c53a31 4b839b5f b914896b 8ad165de dd46a159 6aac5f86 2d75058c>;
            DataValueCollection = <78dce1b0 9f20a1a9 15004f99 65d71d00 46e7c949 80d599ea 622b2574 be9245a4>;
            DateValue = <54571596 1267b4f2 5f14ee12 a0be1b3f 53d79056 7d612f33 e827b90e 7c4c847b>;
            DirectoryItem = <b716a315 e40d91b6 18bb918e ab448086 48bc62b2 5a26e959 2c4a0cb4 8fc8d319>;
            DirectoryNode = <c718b896 a2a90890 596409a2 c50240aa 1e5e347c f9d9c4df 1a5567fe 8bca7ed3>;
            DoubleValue = <b63cba59 de2b200e 199c5ec4 ce17494a a8df75be bac353c0 3c5d9af7 fbf36240>;
            Group = <0e912576 760d5fd4 df8a5bbe 13b7922d 6760a046 ea6fee68 3fcd4bd4 c9de7b3b>;
            Inspection = <e7fc6688 bee2906d 8f8b7f5e 4f69d1da 59bdbb17 0a620529 c0abc426 d164a44f>;
            InspectionMetaData = <982fe134 141245a4 97ca1cde aaa04843 90746c85 80ddedcc ed63b9a4 b3d40477>;
            IntegerValue = <97fbd40d a463d4ed 282aa03b 4b5892fe 7fcac137 b4cc590b 03d79bb9 cfee4517>;
            Observation = <651371ad be372494 10e31b83 509db973 6021af3b 79895e59 f38e0a9f 0b35a63e>;
            ObservationGroup = <92f680bb b4b5243c 83b665e6 35e0d569 634aa24f 455de69e c8c3b666 84c6a858>;
            Project = <97879f96 cdc99c88 6e6a614f aa81519b 2ba1f415 e4424a57 66d3f32e 3700829f>;
            ProjectPreferredTemplate = <35381035 33dac226 aaeee194 fcd8ad4c e5c5506f a2c597ce 24ba7256 6f34f084>;
            SchemaDataRepresentation = <c1843de9 2192b6f8 8f68d807 d5b0d2ac ab276b3c 67c48dc4 f363d92d 89ce1019>;
            StringValue = <a7948007 c3454244 7cea0dcd c85b69b5 db5501fb 35e2a242 31907b97 558f1fb0>;
            TemplateMetaData = <8f0702e9 8bbb5d4f 71c6a455 2a344af6 e967b2bb abcf05d3 96cd9ffc 328fe362>;
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
            ""
        );
        NSStoreType = SQLite;
        NSStoreUUID = "4512A0DB-E887-4294-9E75-840B9861ECA8";
        "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
    };
    reason = "Can't find model for source store";
}
2015-01-21 11:01:11.340 Marq[2699:607] -[AISDataService persistentStoreCoordinator] line 1410 $ Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134130.)" UserInfo=0x6b58f220 {URL=file:///Users/aerion/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/71815540-57DE-49BF-A6F6-69500A54281F/data/Applications/EE5B15A6-A5ED-46EB-9DFD-B6B54353E35B/Documents/ARUPInspect_Schema.sqlite, metadata={
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 479;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
        Asset = <4b2b421f 4295c02f 89b5a2e8 1c4fc3e9 2b515eca 95e89ad6 e65c891d f82b1090>;
        BooleanValue = <3e1758f6 0f04f670 5c150cd4 55f0a0eb b5c1a17e 8b1abdcc ab7044ba fd02dd5e>;
        Client = <c52499f9 a0f482f7 9bdcb115 8217e157 1861f63a e926b55c e7cc85bb b4044464>;
        DataValue = <43afe89a 90c53a31 4b839b5f b914896b 8ad165de dd46a159 6aac5f86 2d75058c>;
        DataValueCollection = <78dce1b0 9f20a1a9 15004f99 65d71d00 46e7c949 80d599ea 622b2574 be9245a4>;
        DateValue = <54571596 1267b4f2 5f14ee12 a0be1b3f 53d79056 7d612f33 e827b90e 7c4c847b>;
        DirectoryItem = <b716a315 e40d91b6 18bb918e ab448086 48bc62b2 5a26e959 2c4a0cb4 8fc8d319>;
        DirectoryNode = <c718b896 a2a90890 596409a2 c50240aa 1e5e347c f9d9c4df 1a5567fe 8bca7ed3>;
        DoubleValue = <b63cba59 de2b200e 199c5ec4 ce17494a a8df75be bac353c0 3c5d9af7 fbf36240>;
        Group = <0e912576 760d5fd4 df8a5bbe 13b7922d 6760a046 ea6fee68 3fcd4bd4 c9de7b3b>;
        Inspection = <e7fc6688 bee2906d 8f8b7f5e 4f69d1da 59bdbb17 0a620529 c0abc426 d164a44f>;
        InspectionMetaData = <982fe134 141245a4 97ca1cde aaa04843 90746c85 80ddedcc ed63b9a4 b3d40477>;
        IntegerValue = <97fbd40d a463d4ed 282aa03b 4b5892fe 7fcac137 b4cc590b 03d79bb9 cfee4517>;
        Observation = <651371ad be372494 10e31b83 509db973 6021af3b 79895e59 f38e0a9f 0b35a63e>;
        ObservationGroup = <92f680bb b4b5243c 83b665e6 35e0d569 634aa24f 455de69e c8c3b666 84c6a858>;
        Project = <97879f96 cdc99c88 6e6a614f aa81519b 2ba1f415 e4424a57 66d3f32e 3700829f>;
        ProjectPreferredTemplate = <35381035 33dac226 aaeee194 fcd8ad4c e5c5506f a2c597ce 24ba7256 6f34f084>;
        SchemaDataRepresentation = <c1843de9 2192b6f8 8f68d807 d5b0d2ac ab276b3c 67c48dc4 f363d92d 89ce1019>;
        StringValue = <a7948007 c3454244 7cea0dcd c85b69b5 db5501fb 35e2a242 31907b97 558f1fb0>;
        TemplateMetaData = <8f0702e9 8bbb5d4f 71c6a455 2a344af6 e967b2bb abcf05d3 96cd9ffc 328fe362>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "4512A0DB-E887-4294-9E75-840B9861ECA8";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
}, reason=Can't find model for source store}, {
    URL = "file:///Users/aerion/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/71815540-57DE-49BF-A6F6-69500A54281F/data/Applications/EE5B15A6-A5ED-46EB-9DFD-B6B54353E35B/Documents/ARUPInspect_Schema.sqlite";
    metadata =     {
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 479;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
            Asset = <4b2b421f 4295c02f 89b5a2e8 1c4fc3e9 2b515eca 95e89ad6 e65c891d f82b1090>;
            BooleanValue = <3e1758f6 0f04f670 5c150cd4 55f0a0eb b5c1a17e 8b1abdcc ab7044ba fd02dd5e>;
            Client = <c52499f9 a0f482f7 9bdcb115 8217e157 1861f63a e926b55c e7cc85bb b4044464>;
            DataValue = <43afe89a 90c53a31 4b839b5f b914896b 8ad165de dd46a159 6aac5f86 2d75058c>;
            DataValueCollection = <78dce1b0 9f20a1a9 15004f99 65d71d00 46e7c949 80d599ea 622b2574 be9245a4>;
            DateValue = <54571596 1267b4f2 5f14ee12 a0be1b3f 53d79056 7d612f33 e827b90e 7c4c847b>;
            DirectoryItem = <b716a315 e40d91b6 18bb918e ab448086 48bc62b2 5a26e959 2c4a0cb4 8fc8d319>;
            DirectoryNode = <c718b896 a2a90890 596409a2 c50240aa 1e5e347c f9d9c4df 1a5567fe 8bca7ed3>;
            DoubleValue = <b63cba59 de2b200e 199c5ec4 ce17494a a8df75be bac353c0 3c5d9af7 fbf36240>;
            Group = <0e912576 760d5fd4 df8a5bbe 13b7922d 6760a046 ea6fee68 3fcd4bd4 c9de7b3b>;
            Inspection = <e7fc6688 bee2906d 8f8b7f5e 4f69d1da 59bdbb17 0a620529 c0abc426 d164a44f>;
            InspectionMetaData = <982fe134 141245a4 97ca1cde aaa04843 90746c85 80ddedcc ed63b9a4 b3d40477>;
            IntegerValue = <97fbd40d a463d4ed 282aa03b 4b5892fe 7fcac137 b4cc590b 03d79bb9 cfee4517>;
            Observation = <651371ad be372494 10e31b83 509db973 6021af3b 79895e59 f38e0a9f 0b35a63e>;
            ObservationGroup = <92f680bb b4b5243c 83b665e6 35e0d569 634aa24f 455de69e c8c3b666 84c6a858>;
            Project = <97879f96 cdc99c88 6e6a614f aa81519b 2ba1f415 e4424a57 66d3f32e 3700829f>;
            ProjectPreferredTemplate = <35381035 33dac226 aaeee194 fcd8ad4c e5c5506f a2c597ce 24ba7256 6f34f084>;
            SchemaDataRepresentation = <c1843de9 2192b6f8 8f68d807 d5b0d2ac ab276b3c 67c48dc4 f363d92d 89ce1019>;
            StringValue = <a7948007 c3454244 7cea0dcd c85b69b5 db5501fb 35e2a242 31907b97 558f1fb0>;
            TemplateMetaData = <8f0702e9 8bbb5d4f 71c6a455 2a344af6 e967b2bb abcf05d3 96cd9ffc 328fe362>;
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
            ""
        );
        NSStoreType = SQLite;
        NSStoreUUID = "4512A0DB-E887-4294-9E75-840B9861ECA8";
        "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
    };
    reason = "Can't find model for source store";
}
```

Comment: Do you have previous versions of the app which included a compiled copy of this version of the model?

Comment: Yes I do. It's archived in Xcode, plus up on TestFlight. Is there a way I can get the model from that?

Comment: This answer fixed the problem for me: stackoverflow.com/a/33078239/1069884

Comment: See my answer [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847537/core-data-file-contents-couldnt-be-opened/47330002#47330002). It worked for me at least. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you're getting when trying to re-create the missing version is almost certainly because you're not re-creating it in exactly the same way. If you're at all unsure, the simplest thing is to try again. There's no reason it shouldn't work if the new one you create is an **exact** match for the old one.

If you can't do that, you can restore the model from the app store copy of the app using the following approach:

If you're starting with an Xcode archive (a `.xcarchive`), that's just a file package containing the app bundle and some other stuff. Browse that to find the `momd` containing **all** of your Core Data models, then look inside that package to find the single `mom` that matches your missing version. Copy that file somewhere outside of the archive.

If you're starting with an `ipa`, that's just a zip file containing the app. Unzip it with whatever unzip tool you like, then proceed as above to find the right `mom`.

The `mom` file is the compiled model, but unlike source code, model compilation can be reversed. Create a new model version in Xcode and delete *everything* in it so that it's completely empty. Then go to the **Editor** menu and select **Import...**. Import the `mom` file you found above.

You should now have a Core Data model version that exactly corresponds to the compiled model from your app. **Commit it to your source code repository** so it'll be around next time.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still can't get it to work. I imported my v15 `mom` file and it's still giving me the same error. Comparing the hashes in the error (now pasted in my question) reveals that two of the models are different, but I have no idea why they would be different; I don't recall changing them for quite a while. And in any case, I'm using the `mom` file from the binary sent to TestFlight...

Comment: The error you're getting is "Can't find model for source store". That indicates that the `mom` you used does not actually correspond with your current persistent store file. Maybe you grabbed the wrong one by mistake? Or maybe when you created the new model version you accidentally made it current, when it's not. It might also help to look at this answer from last year where I explained the same thing a little differently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306257/core-data-cant-find-model-for-source-store

Comment: Because I suspect I might be doing something wrong, I wanted to clarify something. I have 15 `xcdatamodel` versions in my `xcdatamodeld`. The most recent of which is also the current one (v15) and also the one with the missing `contents` file. If I make a new version (v16) based of v14, clear the contents and import the v15 `mom` file, I still can't build because of the missing `contents` file. If I copy that file from either v14 or v16 I get an error like the one above. (different hashes though). What am I missing?

Comment: Aha! What I ended up doing was copy the v14 `contents` file into the v15 `xcdatamodel` (which didn't work), then see which hashes didn't match and copied those models from the new v16 over the top of v15s (removing v15s version of those tables also). At first it still didn't work, but I had to collapse 2-way relationships into one by selecting the correct inverse of the relationships, making it match again. In hindsight, this is probably the thing I was missing from the start. Thanks Tom.

Comment: @TomHarrington. Could you help me in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43279438/nspersistentstorecoordinator-has-no-persistent-storesschema-mismatch-or-migrati

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I get the error after importing the copied version: "Error importing Meta Object Model (MOM) file." It creates all entities but it imports only the attributes from one entity. I have even tried to import it into an old model version of previous project version. Nothing worked.. any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to fix that with a Core Data migration : http://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration

Comment: Are you saying to create a new migration again? I'm currently on version 15 (the one with the file missing). I tried just creating a new migration based on v14, and added the missing tables and so forth, but it wouldn't build. So I tried copying the `contents` file (alternately from v14 and the new v16) to v15, and it will build, but still crash when it tries to access the db.